# Transfer value from one object to another

Tags: javascript, object

I have this two object below

```
const Object1 = {
    0: {questions: "A", a: "Choice 1", b: "Choice 2", c: "Choice 3"},
    1: {questions: "B", a: "Choice 1", b: "Choice 2", c: "Choice 3"},
    2: {questions: "C", a: "Choice 1", b: "Choice 2", c: "Choice 3"}
}

const Object2 = {
    0: "One", 
    1: "Two", 
    2: "Three"
}
```

I want to change the all value in questions to "One", "Two", "Three" like below :

```
{
    0: {questions: "One", a: "Choice 1", b: "Choice 2", c: "Choice 3"},
    1: {questions: "Two", a: "Choice 1", b: "Choice 2", c: "Choice 3"},
    2: {questions: "Three", a: "Choice 1", b: "Choice 2", c: "Choice 3"}
}
```

Really appreciate if anyone could help me on this.

Comment: It's simple algorithmic. You need to loop over the keys of the object(s) and do your assignments

Answer (score 0):

Could something like this work in your case?

Utilising a switch-case instead of object 2, because object 2 has no real mapping from the letters A, B and C to any of its values.

```
function letterToNumberMapper(letter) {
   switch (letter) {
      case "A": return "One";
      case "B": return "Two";
      case "C": return "Three";
   }
}

object1 = object1.map(item => {
   return {...item, questions: letterToNumberMapper(item.questions)}
});
```